# variable in mysql query, NOW() + INTERVAL $variable

Tags: php, mysql

$someDays=2;

how to put this variable into this mysql query?

these do not work:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users (validity) VALUES (NOW() + INTERVAL '$someDays' DAY) WHERE id='$id'");
mysql_query("UPDATE users (validity) VALUES (NOW() + INTERVAL $someDays DAY) WHERE id='$id'");
mysql_query("UPDATE users (validity) VALUES (NOW() + INTERVAL '".$someDays."' DAY) WHERE id='$id'");
mysql_query("UPDATE users (validity) VALUES (NOW() + INTERVAL ".$someDays." DAY) WHERE id='$id'");
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are connected to the database?

Comment: UPDATE doesn't have VALUES http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html - `UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]` - You may have meant to use INSERT INTO. Or use `UPDATE table SET...`

Comment: If youre updating, your going to want to `set`.

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments you are using `INSERT` syntax but attempting to do an `UPDATE`. Something like the following should work:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET validity = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL $someDays DAY) WHERE id = $id");
```

EDIT:

To add `$someDays` days to the existing `validity` value you can do

```
… SET validity = DATE_ADD(validity, INTERVAL $someDays DAY) …
```

If you need to set it to a specific time you can use PHP to do the date addition:

```
$userVal='2014-11-06 20:52:05'; 

$newUserVal = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+ '.$someDays.' days', strtotime($userVal)));

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET validity = '$newUserVal' WHERE id = $id");
```

Comment: @GrzegorzNowak 18 mins. ago, you said this didn't work. So, why did you accept it just now?

Comment: I am so sorry, it works perfectly I just answered wrong comment o.O

Comment: @GrzegorzNowak I understand. Thanks for clearing that up, it was confusing. Glad this matter was resolved, *cheers*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Could you even tell you how to use variable with data (like this: '2014-11-06 20:52:05') instead of NOW(), please?

Comment: Use `DATETIME` as your column type, it will enter the time/date using `NOW()` as you shown `2014-11-06 20:52:05`, which is better to use. Otherwise, you will have more code to add and it's much easier doing it that way, believe me. @GrzegorzNowak

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yea I know that I am using it :), but I wanted to add variable with date instead of NOW(), to add to my date some days. But seems it not working at all. $userVal='2014-11-06 20:52:05';
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET validity = DATE_ADD($userVal, INTERVAL $someDays DAY) WHERE id = $id");

Comment: @GrzegorzNowak You're best asking a new question.

Comment: @cOle2 Quite nice of you, yet it should have been a new question. Oh well, I'm not going to argue lol

Answer (score 2):

The most readable way to do this would be like this -

```
"UPDATE `users` SET `validity` = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL '".$someDays."' DAY) WHERE `id`='".$id."' "
```

You're trying to use syntax from an INSERT rather than an  UPDATE. In addition, if you're going to use variables in a certain way in the query you should do that for all variables in the query to maintain consistency and readability.

Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Comment: Only the fish & birds like worms; not me. But I did +1 though ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "this do not work"? Did you get a syntax error or some other issue? If so we're going to need to see more of your code and any errors that you're getting.

Comment: Do you have any error checking in your script? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php tag error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The OP's on something. Just accepted the other answer where OP stated it also didn't work 18 mins. prior. DUH. Some just aren't cut out for coding. *Doing a burger flip*.

Comment: The syntax for `DATE_ADD()` in this answer is wrong which is probably why the OP said it doesn't work.

Comment: Roger that @cOle2 - I skipped over that in my head. It's fixed.

Comment: @cOle2 I have no problem with the OP accepting your answer, I'm all for it. What I don't get is that the OP posted (and deleted) the comment left under your answer stating that it did not work, which is why I gave my head a shake as to why he/she said that to start with. I even +1 your also. *Sharing the wealth* ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to add days in current date. you can't perform two operation at one time so try to update or try to insert.

```
mysql_query("insert into  users (validity) VALUES (select DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ".$someDays." DAY) );
```